Trying to use wagmi with safe sdk,but getting Error: invalid account
Here's hook which i am using
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SafeApiKit from "@safe-global/api-kit";
import { SafeFactory, SafeAccountConfig } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import { useEthersSigner } from "./use-signer";

interface CreateSafeProps {
  chainId: number;
  owner: `0x${string}`;
}

export const CreateSafe: React.FC<CreateSafeProps> = ({ chainId, owner }) => {
  const [safeAddress, setSafeAddress] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const signer = useEthersSigner();

  const handleCreateSafe = async () => {
    if (!chainId) {
      setError("Chain ID is required");
      return;
    }
    if (!owner) {
      setError("Owner is required");
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      console.log("Creating Safe...");
      console.log("Owner: ", owner);

      const apiKit = new SafeApiKit({
        chainId: BigInt(chainId),
      });

      const protocolKit = await SafeFactory.init({
        provider: "https://sepolia.base.org",
        signer: signer?.address,
      });

      const config: SafeAccountConfig = {
        owners: [owner, owner],
        threshold: 2,
      };

      const safe = await protocolKit.deploySafe({
        safeAccountConfig: config,
        options: {
          from: signer?.address,
        }
      });

      const address = await safe.getAddress();
      setSafeAddress(address);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setError(err instanceof Error ? err.message : String(err));
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button 
        onClick={handleCreateSafe}
        disabled={isLoading}
        className="w-full py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-gray-900"
      >
        {isLoading ? 'Creating Safe...' : 'Create Safe'}
      </button>
      {error && <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{error}</p>}
      {safeAddress && <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-green-600">Safe created at address: {safeAddress}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

and here's the useEtherSigner
import { BrowserProvider, JsonRpcSigner } from 'ethers'
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import type { Account, Chain, Client, Transport } from 'viem'
import { type Config, useConnectorClient } from 'wagmi'

export function clientToSigner(client: Client<Transport, Chain, Account>) {
  const { account, chain, transport } = client
  const network = {
    chainId: chain.id,
    name: chain.name,
    ensAddress: chain.contracts?.ensRegistry?.address,
  }
  const provider = new BrowserProvider(transport, network)
  const signer = new JsonRpcSigner(provider, account.address)
  return signer
}

/** Hook to convert a viem Wallet Client to an ethers.js Signer. */
export function useEthersSigner({ chainId }: { chainId?: number } = {}) {
  const { data: client } = useConnectorClient<Config>({ chainId })
  return useMemo(() => (client ? clientToSigner(client) : undefined), [client])
}

I'm using wagmi, and have structured my providers like this
'use client';
import { base, mainnet, sepolia, zora } from "viem/chains";
import { http } from "wagmi";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { PrivyProvider } from "@privy-io/react-auth";
import { WagmiProvider } from "@privy-io/wagmi";
import type { PrivyClientConfig } from "@privy-io/react-auth";
import { createConfig  } from "@privy-io/wagmi";
import { safe } from 'wagmi/connectors'

// Replace this with your Privy config
export const privyConfig: PrivyClientConfig = {
  embeddedWallets: {
    createOnLogin: "users-without-wallets",
    requireUserPasswordOnCreate: true,
    noPromptOnSignature: false,
  },
  loginMethods: ["wallet", "email", "sms"],
  appearance: {
    showWalletLoginFirst: true,
  },
};

export const config = createConfig({
  chains: [mainnet, base, zora],
  connectors: [safe()],
  transports: {
    [mainnet.id]: http(),
    [base.id]: http(),
    [zora.id]: http(),
  },
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <PrivyProvider appId="" config={privyConfig}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <WagmiProvider config={config}>{children}</WagmiProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </PrivyProvider>
  );
}

I'm facing the following error
provider-jsonrpc.js:798  Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid account
    at JsonRpcProvider.getSigner (provider-jsonrpc.js:798:1)
    at async SafeProvider.getSafeProxyFactoryContract (SafeProvider.js:72:1)
    at async getProxyFactoryContract (safeDeploymentContracts.js:19:1)
    at async SafeFactory._SafeFactory_initializeSafeFactory (SafeFactory.js:123:1)
    at async SafeFactory.init (SafeFactory.js:37:1)
    at async createSafe (use-safe.tsx:22:23)


Instead of:
const protocolKit = await SafeFactory.init({
    provider: "https://sepolia.base.org",
    signer: signer?.address,
  });

Could you try:
import { useWallets } from '@privy-io/react-auth'

export const CreateSafe: React.FC<CreateSafeProps> = ({ chainId, owner }) => {
  // ...
  const { wallets } = useWallets();
  // ...

  const handleCreateSafe = async () => {
      // ...
      const protocolKit = await SafeFactory.init({
        provider: await wallets[0].getEthereumProvider(),
        signer: wallets[0].address,
      });
      // ...
  }

You don't need to use useEthersSigner anymore, since you are using the provider returned from the connected wallet(s) via Privy.
Please note also that adding twice the owner address in your SafeAccountConfig will result in an error. To fix it, please edit it so you have instead:
  const config: SafeAccountConfig = {
    owners: [owner],
    threshold: 1
  }

Does that make sense? Please let me know if that solved the problem  Thanks in advance.
Best, Louis

signer is of type string in the SDK and in the code signer is of the JsonRpcSigner type, so that is not working and throwing error.

Apologies, I had edited the wrong part of the solution. I have modified my answer, could you try again by passing the full provider object instead of the RPC URL? Best, Louis

getting this error now, app-index.tsx:25  TypeError: invalid EIP-1193 provider (argument="ethereum", value={  }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.2)
using provider from useEtherSigner

Thanks for following up! I've edited the answer above again to provide a working version of the code. I hope it solved the issue. Best, Louis

Thanks, this helped
